# Dynamic ng-repeat using ui param value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to do something like `ng-repeat="statement in {{ range }}Statements"` where range is a ui param value that can be pos, neu and neg depending on the URL:

```
/#/sidemenu-statements/1/pos
/#/sidemenu-statements/1/neg
/#/sidemenu-statements/1/neu
```

It would allow me to consolidate the three lists below... is it possible to do this?

If not what would be a better approach?

**statements.view.html**

```
<div ng-controller="StatementsController">
    <!-- List of positive statements -->
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="statement in posStatements | orderBy: '-timestamp'" ng-if="range==='pos'">
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon {{ statement.accountIcon }}"></i> 
            <h2>{{ statement.accountTag }}</h2>
            <span am-time-ago="{{ statement.timestamp }}"></span>
        </div>  
        <div class="item item-body">
            <span>{{ statement.statement }}</span>
            <div align="center"><p>We've assessed this post as <strong>{{ range }}</strong>. What do you think?</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button button-balanced"><i class="icon ion-happy"></i></a>
            <a class="button button-dark">Skip</a>
            <a class="button button-assertive"><i class="icon ion-sad"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List of neutral statements -->
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="statement in negStatements | orderBy: '-timestamp'" ng-if="range==='neu'">
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon {{ statement.accountIcon }}"></i> 
            <h2>{{ statement.accountTag }}</h2>
            <span am-time-ago="{{ statement.timestamp }}"></span>
        </div>  
        <div class="item item-body">
            <span>{{ statement.statement }}</span>
            <div align="center"><p>We've assessed this post as <strong>{{ range }}</strong>. What do you think?</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button button-balanced"><i class="icon ion-happy"></i></a>
            <a class="button button-dark">Skip</a>
            <a class="button button-assertive"><i class="icon ion-sad"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List of negative statements -->
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="statement in negStatements | orderBy: '-timestamp'" ng-if="range==='neg'">
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon {{ statement.accountIcon }}"></i> 
            <h2>{{ statement.accountTag }}</h2>
            <span am-time-ago="{{ statement.timestamp }}"></span>
        </div>  
        <div class="item item-body">
            <span>{{ statement.statement }}</span>
            <div align="center"><p>We've assessed this post as <strong>{{ range }}</strong>. What do you think?</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button button-balanced"><i class="icon ion-happy"></i></a>
            <a class="button button-dark">Skip</a>
            <a class="button button-assertive"><i class="icon ion-sad"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Could you just evaluate if it is neg/neu/pos in a controller, bind that to a new field on the $scope obj, and pass that into the ng-repeat instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
ng-repeat="statement in getStatements(range)"
```

and add this function in the controller (you can use a switch/case structure if you're not a fan of the string concatenation):

```
$scope.getStatements = function(range) {
   return $scope[range + "Statements"];
};
```